# Does evaporation occur while boiling as well?

Tags: physical-chemistry, boiling-point, vapor-pressure

If evaporation were to occur when a liquid was being boiled, then the amount of liquid changing phase would also depend on the surface area of the liquid exposed to the atmosphere (as evaporation rate increases with surface area). However I have read that the surface area doesn't affect the amount of liquid changing phase while the liquid is boiling.

So does evaporation not occur while the liquid is boiling?

Comment: Boiling **is** evaporation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaporation occurs while a random molecule from the bulk collides with the surface molecules and though the upper molecules are less tightly bounded, they gain the energy due to collision and escape from the liquid surface as vapours. But at low temperature this collision frequency is very less. In boiling, we provide heat to the liquid, due to which the collision frequency increases and upper surface molecules more fastly escape. So, boiling includes evaporation. Now for boiling, surface area doesn't matter as the heat which we externally supplied plays a dominant role compared to the surface area of liquid exposed to atmosphere in boiling. The surface area plays negligible role in boiling.